# How many Amps can a Nano Arduino hold for LED project

Tags: arduino-nano, led, current

I'm really new at this, and here is my doubt. What if I need to light 120x WS2812B (5v)LEDs (link: [LEDs](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1m-4m-5m-WS2812B-Smart-led-pixel-strip-Black-White-PCB-30-60-144-leds-m/2036819167.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.274263c0i8fcIU)) using an Arduino Nano? if it takes 60 mAh each pixel, the total amount needed should be around 7,200 mA.

Could I use the same 5V/ 8A power supply ([PowerSupply](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5V-LED-Power-Supply-1A-2A-3A-6A-8A-10A-Switching-Adapter-AC110-240V-AC-to/32810906485.html?spm=a219c.10010108.1000001.12.7eb35ccdAeVPQZ)) for the Nano board and lights? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance, and sorry my ignorance on this area.

Comment: Check your units.  Charge (e.g. in mAh a unit of electrical capacity, or how much current can be supplied over a given time).  Current is the rate of charge flow (e.g. in mA).  As written your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 120 LEDs * 60 mA = 7200 mA = 7.2A

An Arduino Nano will use 19 mA ([Arduino Nano Tech Spec)](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano). Of course, if you add a power LED, or other components it will add, but it will likely be less than a few 100 mA. So that totals to max 7.4A.

It's always good to have some headroom which is 0.6A in your case (that's enough).

Actually what's happening is as follows:
- Your 8 mA gives the current the components request
- Your Nano requests 19 mA
- Your LEDs require 7.200 mA.

As long as the voltage is the same (5V for both the LEDs, Nano, and adapter), and the components do not request more than 8 A summed up (with some headroom), the adapter will deliver the current needed. If all components request more than 8 A, than high likely the adapter will break (and possibly the attached components too).

Comment: Thanks Michel, I just wanted to make sure that I don't burn the board on my first attempt  ;)

Comment: You're welcome .. .you can wait for more answers, if an answer is helpful, upvote it, if the answer answers your question in a satisfactory way, accept the answer.

Comment: @juasmilla, why would you think that you would burn the Nano? .... how are you planning to connect the LEDs?

Answer (score 0):

It can supply both, *as long as they are supplied separately*; the LEDs must not be supplied through the Nano board, but connected directly from the power supply.

Comment: Fine, connecting the ground on both I suppose... Thanks for all your inputs! brilliant Arduino World, and of course, its community!!

Comment: @Yes connect ground together